# Can Log4j's SocketAppenders support a many-to-one (or 3-to-2) pipeline?

Tags: sockets, tcp, log4j, log4j2, appender

I would like to implement the following logging architecture:

[image]

whereby I have three clients logging via a `<SocketAppender>` to a single load balancer (Nginx in this case), and just two log listeners (LogServer1, Logserver2) to consume the TCP traffic from all three clients.

Can all three apps' messages be consumed simultaneously like this? I have been prototyping and I am repeatedly finding that each client gets exclusive access to one listener, leaving latecomer clients' messages dropped completely. There must be N servers to handle N clients. Is this true?

Comment: No. Unless there is something seriously wrong at the server or load balancer end it should handle any number of clients. Your observation about dropped messages cannot possibly be correct for a TCP connection.

Comment: Actually, I tried this same 3:2 setup with netcat (both on the client and server) and still got the same problem - the 3rd client's data was completely ignored. Should the server netcat processes be receiving lines from all 3 clients?